# Where can I find a step by step guide to become a node, and use the lightning network?

Tags: lightning-network

I am looking for information about how to run a node on the Lightning Network and start using it? Is there a step-by-step guide available somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Some information can be found here:
https://medium.com/@dougvk/run-your-own-mainnet-lightning-node-2d2eab628a8b

But you should ask yourself first what goals do you want to achieve? Estabilishing LN node is not a "make-me-rich-quickly" investment.

Answer (score 1):

This is a [tutorial detailing how to set up and start using c-lightning](https://hackernoon.com/harnessing-lightning-for-instant-bitcoin-transacting-a-tutorial-3b9dcdc00552). It walks you through setting up bitcoind, c-lightning and your first transaction.

Additionally, you can find a link collection with information on Lightning, including several setup guides, at [lnroute.com](https://lnroute.com/).

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to run a dedicated "always on" node, eg. on a Raspberry Pi, I can recommend my own guide :)

**Beginner’s Guide to ️⚡Lightning️⚡ on a Raspberry Pi**
https://github.com/Stadicus/guides/blob/master/raspibolt/README.md